# Split dataframe columns into vectors in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, split

I have a dataframe as such:

```
Number <- c(1,2,3)
Number2 <- c(10,12,14)
Letter <- c("A","B","C")
df <- data.frame(Number,Number2,Letter)
```

I would like to split the df into its respective three columns, each one becoming a vector with the respective column name. In essence, the output should look exactly like the original three input vectors in the above example.

I have tried the **split** function and also using **for loop**, but without success.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `unclass` as `data.frame` is a `list` with additional attributes.  By `unclass`ing, it removes the `data.frame` attribute

```
unclass(df)
```

---

Or another option is `asplit` with `MARGIN` specified as 2

```
asplit(df, 2)
```

NOTE: Both of them return a `named` `list`.  If we intend to create new objects in the global env, use `list2env` (not recommended though)

Comment: Thank you. That works very well. How would I get the arguments from the list into separate vectors in my environment though?

Comment: @jestor As I mentioned `list2env` with `list2env(df, .GlobalEnv)` which is not recommended as it creates lots of objects in the global env

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to create these as vectors if the global environment, use `list2env`:

```
df <- data.frame(Number = c(1, 2, 3), 
                 Number2 = c(10, 12, 14), 
                 Letter = c("A", "B", "C"))

list2env(df, .GlobalEnv)
## <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
ls()
## [1] "df"      "Letter"  "Number"  "Number2"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `c` or`as.list`

```
> c(df)
$Number
[1] 1 2 3

$Number2
[1] 10 12 14

$Letter
[1] "A" "B" "C"

> as.list(df)
$Number
[1] 1 2 3

$Number2
[1] 10 12 14

$Letter
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

list2env is clearly the easiest way, but if you want to do it with a for loop it can also be achieved.

The "tricky" part is to make a new vector based on the column names inside the for loop. If you just write

```
 names(df[i]) <- input
```

a vector will not be created.

A workaround is to use paste to create a string with the new vector name and what should be in it, then use "eval(parse(text=)" to evaluate this expression.

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but seems to work.

```
for (i in colnames(df)){
  vector_name <- names(df[i])
  expression_to_be_evaluated <- paste(vector_name, "<- df[[i]]")
  eval(parse(text=expression_to_be_evaluated))
}

> Letter
[1] A B C
Levels: A B C
> Number
[1] 1 2 3
> Number2
[1] 10 12 14
```